# Field value showing null value

Tags: json, reactjs, output, undefined, state

```
const book1 = this.state.books[0]; //giving one book
console.log(book1); //output->{id: 1, bookname: "Physics", price: 600, author: "ABC", pages: 567, …}
const {id,bookname,price,author,pages,category} = {book1};
console.log(price); //output->undefined
```

I have already tried a lot of things. How To get the value of particular property?
Here is the JSON file:

```
 [
    {
            "id": 1,
            "bookname": "Physics",
            "price": 600,
            "author": "ABC",
            "pages": 567,
            "category" : "Science"
    }

]
```

Comment: For the next time, please provide the correct style formatting of the question, according to (https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript object destructuring shown is invalid, because of the curly braces around `book1`.

Remove those braces:

```js
const { id, bookname, price, author, pages, category } = book1;
```

Here's a simpler example:

```js
> const book = { price: 600 }
undefined
> const { price } = book
undefined
> price
600
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'book1' as it is undefined.

  39 |        
> 41 |        const {id,bookname,price,author,pages,category} = book1;
     | ^  42 |        console.log(bookname);

Comment: `id` of `book1` is undefined. This can be caused by many things: destructuring before the data is loaded, typo, one of the books does not have an id, etc. That's your next challenge @NancyGupta!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Jake mentioned, what you're trying to do here is called destructuring assignment. So as per the correct syntax,

```
const { id, bookname, price, author, pages, category } = book1;
```

this would actually mean,

```
const id=book1.id
const bookname=book1.bookname
```

And so on. You could have a look at https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment for more information on destructuring assignment.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'book1' as it is undefined. 39 | > 41 | const {id,bookname,price,author,pages,category} = book1; | ^ 42 | console.log(bookname);